# Order by clause, huge performance drop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the following query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.CODE, A.NAME, (SUBQUERY CALCULATING SALES)
FROM PRODUCTS A
JOIN PRODUCTSALES B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

The query returns 250 rows in less than a second. If I add in the end `ORDER BY A.CODE` or `ORDER BY A.NAME` the query returns in 20 seconds.

I cannot understand why it takes so long to sort 250 rows of data. This behavior is absent if the order column is an integer like A.ID.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Any indexes? Cold/hot data? Is A.ID the primary key?

Comment: If A.ID is a primary key it probably has a clustered index, which means it is already sorted. Can you view a query plan? It should give you some more information on what's happening. E.g. missing index.

Comment: Are you using GROUP BY? What dbms are you using this really does matter!

Comment: Have a scout at the execution plan and see what its doing

Comment: Show us the execution plan (in Postgres use `explain (analyze, verbose)` to generate it)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014. A.ID is the primary key. I am not an advanced user and I do not know how to read the execution plan. I generated it using SET STATISTICS XML ON which returned an XML formatted string. Shall I post this here? It seems to me that the ORDER clause is not applied on the final results. If I add the unordered results on a temp table and order the temp table afterwards, performance is not affected.

Comment: I can see the downvotes and I really do not understand what is wrong. Isn;t this site a place where people can ask more knowledgeable people for advice/explanation of a problem/question they have?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I guess people miss table definition(s), indexes, execution plans etc.

Comment: Order by function use sorting and sorting integers is way much faster than sorting varchar

Comment: @Saloom, the downvotes are probably because your question is missing the DDL for creating the tables and indexes. Indexes are especially important for performance. Also, the subquery is missing, which is an important detail. I expect you would also get bad performance if you order by an integer column that has no index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because you are forcing SQL Server to return the rows in an order.

- Sorts can be expensive as it consumes much of the joined tables before operations can be performed
- Clustered/nonclustered indexes already provide an order by of some sort, so the optimizer can be sure of the order.

Normally, SQL Server just grabs the first 250 rows that match without any concern for order or sequential rows and it is done with the Query.

But since you are now insisting the first 250 rows be returned with a specific order, the Optimizer must now use a sort operation between the tables before grabbing the 250 requested rows.

This is why you are seeing the performance hit, since SQL Server must now load much of this matched tables into memory to process.

As for why you do not notice this on the ID column, that is because the order is at least based on a clustered index, so there already is a guaranteed sort order of some kind, so the Optimizer need not load as much to get to 250 rows.

Comment: But, why is it, that the optimizer chooses not to perform the sorts on the final result set? Why does it suppose that I insist on returning an ordered set instead of sorting it afterwards? Isn't it actually a de-optimization strategy, judging from the final result?